# Matrix vector multiplication only if column and row are different

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm implementing the Jacobi iterative method to solve linear systems Ax = b

I have the following code:

```
data.a <- c(3, -1, 1, 3, 6, 2, 3, 3, 7)
A <- matrix(data.a, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

b <- c(1, 0, 4)
Xo <- c(0,0,0)
X <- c(0, 0, 0)

 #A is the matrix:
     #3   -1    1
     #3    6    2
     #3    3    7

#b is the column vector:
#[1, 0, 4]

#and Xo is the previous X computed

for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
  sum = 0
  for(j in 1:ncol(A)){
    if(j != i){
      sum = sum + A[i,j]*Xo[j]
    }
  }

  X[i] = -(1/A[i,i])*(sum - b[i])
}
```

The thing is, because I only multiply and sum up the values `A[i][j]*Xo[j]` for `j != i`
 I am using nested for-loops and use the auxiliar variable sum.

My question is: Could I use something like

```
A[i,] %*% Xo
```

to compute the values of the sum without the nested-for loops?

edit: I found a solution

```
X[i] = -(1/A[i,i])*(A[i,]%*%Xo - A[i,i]*Xo[i] - b[i])
# I subtracted the term A[i,i]*Xo[i] from the product A*Xo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even remove the first loop by making a matrix `R`, whose elements are equal to A except that diagonal elements are zeros.

```
update <- function(x, A, b) {
  D <- diag(diag(A))
  R <- A - D

  sums <- R %*% x
  x <- (b - sums) / diag(D)
  x
}

data.a <- c(3, -1, 1, 3, 6, 2, 3, 3, 7)
A <- matrix(data.a, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
b <- c(1, 0, 4)

x <- c(0, 0, 0)
for (i in 1:100) x <- update(x, A, b)
x

# verify the answer is correct
solve(A, b)
```